# Error generating custom visualization for this control

Tags: xpages

I have a template and a db both on the same server.  I am trying to build my first mobile app with the extension pages mobile  extension library.

All goes fine in the template.  I can see the controls being rendered in the designer.    But when I refresh the nsf from the template the controls are not being rendered in desginer in the nsf.  They show up as yellow tags instead, much like they do when you copy an xpage with extension library controls.

If I try place any extension library control on the page, I get a dialog box that pops up and says "Error Processing Supplied markup for the control Script Interpreter Error line = 3, col=5.   On the page I see "Error generating custom visualization for this control. Ensure source is valid or contact owner".

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Check your namespaces

Comment: Also check to see if the required libraries are selected in the application properties. If this setting didn't carry over during design refresh, Designer won't know what `xe:` means.

Comment: The selected libraries are the same between the tempate and the nsf.   Where is the namespace setting found?

Comment: Bruce, here is an example of a namespace.  (It is at the very top of your source):  <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
 xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

Comment: Namespaces are an xml thing, not unique to Notes.  Like Tim said, if you don't have the xe namespace then designer won't know what to do with the extension library controls (xe:), you then get the yellow tags.

Comment: But I do have the library loaded.  I assume that is on the Advance tab of properties, under XPage Libaries?  The extlib entry is checked on both the DB an the template.

Comment: All of a sudden it is working.  It must have been a server issue.  It is a Dev server and they did do a reboot since I had the issue.  I do have another issue but I think it is just do to a mobile library not being loaded. I'll create another thread if I can't find the answer.  Thnaks for the help.